# How to save data to a txt file or excel file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How to save this data (`i` and `a`) to a `.txt` file or `.xls` file in MATLAB?

```
for i=1:10
   i
   a=i*2
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [csvwrite](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) to write coma separated values to a text file. You can read it in Excel, and it is a text file at the same time

```
i=1:10;
a=i*2;
csvwrite('data.csv', [i; a]);
```

Comment: it is in row form how i can convert it into colume (lets say A1 only). The above code only saved i value and not the a value.how i can save a value?

Comment: @t3st I have fixed that already, it saves both i and a now. The second parameter is a matrix. You can save it with any dimensions: `csvwrite('data.csv', [i; a]');` will save the data as two columns.

Comment: @anginor still its saving in row only, i know that logically [i;a] its a transponse of a matrix,but in excel its still in row form..is csvwrite() can overwrite existing file?

Comment: @t3st You probably did not transpose it. Copy the line from the comment above and execute it. Look at the csv file - it now has two columns. If it has two rows it means you did not transpose the matrix.

Comment: @anginor hey thanxs, when i run that line alone it worked..once more thank you

Answer (score 2):

Matlab provides an file I/O interface similar to that of C: you open a file, output data or formatted text, and close it:

```
f = fopen( "file.txt", "w" );
for i=1:10,
  a=i*2
  fprintf( f, "%d ", a );
end
fclose( f );
```

Answer (score 2):

To save to a text file, there is [fprintf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html), example (from documentation):

```
x = 0:.1:1;
A = [x; exp(x)];

fileID = fopen('exp.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%6s %12s\n','x','exp(x)');
fprintf(fileID,'%6.2f %12.8f\n',A);
fclose(fileID);
```

To save to an excel file, there is [xlswrite](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html), example (from documentation):

```
filename = 'testdata.xlsx';
A = [12.7, 5.02, -98, 63.9, 0, -.2, 56];
xlswrite(filename,A)
```

If you do not have excel installed, this will not work. An alternative is then [csvwrite](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html), which you later on can easily import in excel (on another pc eg).